# Attempt to change the breaks in my ggplot removes the y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

My current ggplot adds a break in the y axis every 2 numbers, which makes it look really busy. When I try to change it, however, I end up removing the entire y axis.

Here is my data:

```
mrk_evyChip <- structure(list(Variety = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Hodag 2018", "Lamoka 2018", 
"Snowden 2018", "Hodag 2019", "Lamoka 2019", "Snowden 2019"), class = "factor"), 
    rate = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", 
    "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), per = c("83%", "76%", "82%", "81%", "81%", "87%", "90%", 
    "83%", "85%", "93%", "90%", "90%", "90%", "90%", "92%", "90%", 
    "89%", "89%", "89%", "90%", "81%", "80%", "80%", "82%", "80%", 
    "83%", "85%", "83%", "82%", "82%")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
    Variety = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Hodag 2018", "Lamoka 2018", 
    "Snowden 2018", "Hodag 2019", "Lamoka 2019", "Snowden 2019"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 
        21:25, 26:30)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Here is my ggplot, with the new code for changing the axis at the end:

```
ChippersPlotMkt <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = mrk_evyChip, aes(y = per, x = Rate)) +
  theme_grey(base_size = 20) +
  facet_wrap(~Variety) +
  ylab("Marketable Percentage") + 
  xlab("Rate (Percentage of ET)") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('125%','100%','75%', '50%', '75%50%')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  scale_y_discrete(breaks= 5)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Remove the scale_y_discrete statement and look again at your y-axis.  The axis labels go from 76, to 80 to 81, non-linear.  Because your percent variable  are characters and not a continuous value, the y-axis is skipping values.  Also it is bad practice to attempt to plot a bar chart without the zero value, it provides a distorted comparison between values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not running because of two things.

1. There is no data frame in your ggplot
2. x should be *rate* not *Rate*

If these things are corrected the problem you are describing is `scale_y_discrete(breaks= 5)`. I think the following is what you are looking for. I have just corrected the two mistakes AND have made changes to `scale_y_discrete`.

Please, also note that I have used the [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/) to prepare this answer. The link is certainly an option to look into the next time you post a question

```r
library(ggplot2)

mrk_evyChip <- structure(list(
  Variety = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L,
    5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
  ), .Label = c(
    "Hodag 2018", "Lamoka 2018",
    "Snowden 2018", "Hodag 2019", "Lamoka 2019", "Snowden 2019"
  ), class = "factor"),
  rate = c(
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "2",
    "3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
  ), per = c(
    "83%", "76%", "82%", "81%", "81%", "87%", "90%",
    "83%", "85%", "93%", "90%", "90%", "90%", "90%", "92%", "90%",
    "89%", "89%", "89%", "90%", "81%", "80%", "80%", "82%", "80%",
    "83%", "85%", "83%", "82%", "82%"
  )
), class = c(
  "grouped_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
  Variety = structure(1:6, .Label = c(
    "Hodag 2018", "Lamoka 2018",
    "Snowden 2018", "Hodag 2019", "Lamoka 2019", "Snowden 2019"
  ), class = "factor"), .rows = list(
    1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20,
    21:25, 26:30
  )
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE))


ggplot(mrk_evyChip) +
  geom_col(data = mrk_evyChip, aes(y = per, x = rate)) +
  theme_grey(base_size = 20) +
  facet_wrap(~Variety) +
  ylab("Marketable Percentage") + 
  xlab("Rate (Percentage of ET)") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('125%','100%','75%', '50%', '75%50%')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = c('80%', '90%'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this! Some of those errors were from copying things over from R, I had the correct rate and dataset when I ran it. Because of the issues with the percentages, I ended up converting the percentage characters to whole numbers and used that as my response instead. Somehow, however, this has made it so that my `scale_x_discrete` line no longer works, and I cannot add the x axis labels. Do you have any idea why this might have happened?

Answer (score 2):

`breaks` tells `ggplot` where you want the tic marks on the y-axis. Since you put "5", this value does not exist in your data. I think you want to do something like this to get what you intended: `scale_y_discrete(breaks= c("76%","82%","87%","92%"))`